# How do you add a dropdown list to a cell in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-apps-script, dropdown

How do you add a dropdown list with items `["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]` to cells `A2:A11` in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

```
const rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .withCriteria(
    SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST,
    [
      ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],
      true,
    ])
  .build();

SpreadsheetApp
  .getActive()
  .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  .getRange(2, 1, 10)
  .setDataValidation(rule);
```

The `true` after `["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]` means `showDropDown=true`

Instead of [`VALUE_IN_LIST`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInList(String,Boolean)) you may want [`VALUE_IN_RANGE`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range,Boolean))

```
const listRange = SpreadsheetApp
  .getActive()
  .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  .getRange('C1:C10');

const rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInRange(listRange, true)
  .build();

SpreadsheetApp
  .getActive()
  .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  .getRange(2, 1, 10)
  .setDataValidation(rule);
```

More information on [`DataValidation`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

A list of all the possible [`DataValidationCriteria`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-criteria)